# Use html tag to send whatsapp message using chat API

Tags: php, whatsapi

I'm using Chat API of whatsApp to send message to recipient with PHP. How can I use html tag in the body to send message ?

```
    $msg ="
     Please visit this link.
    <a href='example.com'>VISIT US</a>
    ";

    $data = [
   'phone' => '+16666666666',
    'body' => "$msg", // Message
    ];
    $json = json_encode($data); // Encode data to JSON
    // URL for request POST /message
    $token = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $instanceId = 'xxxxx';
    $url = 'https://api.chat-api.com/instance'.$instanceId.'/message?token='.$token;
    // Make a POST request
    $options = stream_context_create(['http' => [
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
    'content' => $json
    ]
    ]);
    // Send a request
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $options);
```